# Is there such a thing as a reference rendering for a given PDF?

Tags: pdf

I'm working with a lot of third-party PDFs and since we are thinking about changing our rendering engine, I would like to compare different available engines. However, there are subtle differences in the rendering, so that I had to wonder, what do I have to compare those renderings against, is there any kind of reference renderer? Is it Adobe's Acrobat?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, essentially every user expects every PDF renderer to match Adobe Acrobat.

Note though that the PDF specification does not describe rendering down to the pixel level, so some slight variations is expected and normal.

In particular Font hinting and aliasing are acceptable differences. And of course you can get into CMYK and how to best represent that on a RGB screen, so some variance can happen depending on the color profile selected.

Comment: This strikes me as opinion without source and not fact. Not that I don't agree.

Comment: It is *without source* because Adobe Acrobat is not some kind of "official reference implementation". But Adobe Acrobat *used to be the incarnation of a reference* before PDF became ISO standard because the pdf references were not considered *normative in nature*, so there was only the implementation to look at. Furthermore,  Acrobat still is very widely used and, therefore, forms expectations of many users. Some user groups have other expectations, though, in particular the preview program on macs has many users on that platform.